# pod spec lint fails when pod lib lint succeeds. 'vendored_frameworks' pattern did not match any file

Tags: ios, cocoapods, ios-frameworks, podspec

I made an framework for which I'd like to distribute via CocoaPods.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something stupid. I've included a completed .framework folder in the base directory and I'd like that to be the source for my pod. When I run "pod lib lint", everything seems to be fine but when I run "pod spec lint" I get:

```
- ERROR | [iOS] The `vendored_frameworks` pattern did not match any file.
```

I've tried adding preserve_paths after looking through stackoverflow but that doesn't appear to resolve my issue. From reading the cocoapods document, vendored_frameworks is "The paths of the framework bundles that come shipped with the Pod" so I think it seems fine to use it here.

Here is my podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "X"
  s.version          = "1.0"
  s.summary          = "Summary"
  s.description      = "Description here"
  s.homepage         = "http://www.valid_homepage.com/"
  s.license          = { :type => "Commercial", :text => "See https://www.license_here" }
  s.author           = { "Author" => "author@website.com" }
  s.source           = { :http => "https://storage.googleapis.com/path/to/file" }
  s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/handle'
  s.platform     = :ios, '7.0'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.preserve_paths = 'X.framework'
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'X.framework'
  s.frameworks = 'SystemConfiguration'
  s.library  = 'resolv'
end
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

The .framework directory has the structure

```
Framework
  - Headers (Shortcut)
  - LibraryFile (Shortcut)
  - Versions
    - A
      - Headers (Contains .h file)
      - LibraryFile
    - Current (Shortcut to A directory)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. Basically, the folder structure of any zip you distribute has to match the search path internally. Like if your directory structure is:

```
.podspec
Frameworks/
    - X.framework
```

where

```
s.vendored_frameworks = 'Frameworks/X.framework'
```

Then it seems that when you unzip the http: resource it should have the directory structure

```
Frameworks/
    - X.framework
```

Answer (score 0):

vendored_frameworks is strangly case sensitive,
for example I had lib.zip with Foldername/lib.xcFramework
and

```
vendored_frameworks="Foldername/lib.xcframework" <- that didn't worked for me
vendored_frameworks="foldername/Lib.xcframework" <- that works well
```

same issue without folder, lib.zip with Lib.xcFramework

```
vendored_frameworks="Lib.xcframework" <- that didn't worked for me
vendored_frameworks="lib.xcframework" <- that works well
```

I loosed a lot of time to figure out this, hope this will help someone.